# When I reload solr admin .Error loading class 'solr.SortableIntField' just happend

Tags: django, solr

I did the project follow the 'Django by examples',when i adding a search engine with Solr and Haystack,some wrong happend in building indexes.
  When  i run the following command:

```
python manage.py build_solr_schema
```

I got the following XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

<!--

 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
Save the following output to 'schema.xml' and place it in your Solr configuration directory.
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.

 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<schema name="default" version="1.5">
  <types>
    <fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>
```

It's not complete, and I copy the whole XML to the solr/blog/config/schema.xml
Then I went to http://loaclhost:8984/solr to reload my core
but it's not work

[image]

What should I do to resolve it?